# Escape $ for command line Ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash, command-line

I have a Ruby script where I want to take money as a command line input like this:

```
>ruby myscript.rb Rob $100
```

where $100 is dollars.

However, $ is a special character in bash, which interprets the $100 as $1 and my Ruby script gets "00" as the command line input(ARGV), when I want the complete $100.

Is there a way to get the unescaped version of the dollar field? (I know that '$100' will retain the raw value, but the API I've been given means that the user can't be burdened with remembering to quote all dollar values)

Thanks in advance for any ideas here!

Comment: Have you tried `\$100`

Comment: If it's possible, you can change the syntax from `$100` to `100` or `100USD`.

Comment: If the user has to enter a $, they're going to have to remember to do *something* to it.  Single quotes, backslash, whatever.

Comment: If the user can't handle the (minimal) responsibility of quoting shell metacharacters, have the script prompt for a dollar amount after it is run, instead of taking a command-line argument.

Comment: Use a flag for currency, perhaps `-c USD` and if USD is common, then set it as the default?

Comment: @Linuxios - OS is MacOSX./

Comment: @chepner is right. That is the best way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the command line API or the user, in this case, so I can't do anything that would change the command.

Comment: @Sly, if you have no control then educating the user is the only thing you can do. (that, and cursing the author of the ruby script)

Comment: `set \${1..9}` will work as long as they never type a leading zero in their dollar amounts. (Yes, it's an awful hack.)

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input here. Definitely more options than I thought of myself...it does seem that the prompting option is the best. I interrupt the script to prompt the user. I can still be compliant to the command line spec and avoid the $ parsing issue altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use a bit different approach? Something like this:

```
puts "Provide your name:"
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hey, #{name}, how much are you ready to pay?"
money = gets.chomp
puts "#{name}, thanks for your #{money}"
```

from user's side it will look like:

```
# Provide your name:
# Rob
# Hey, Rob, how much are you ready to pay?
# $100
# Rob, thanks for your $100
```